# Unable to render Zend Form elements in ViewScript

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

**I have Login.php form like this:**

```
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
    }

    public function __construct(){

        // Set method
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $elements = array();

        $element = $this->createElement('text','username');
        $element->setRequired(true);
        $elements[] = $element;

        $element = $this->createElement('password','password');
        $element->setRequired(true);
        $elements[] = $element;

        $this->addElements( $elements );

        $this->setDecorators( array( array( 'viewScript', array( 'viewScript' => '/authentication/login-form.phtml' ) ) ) );
    }
}
```

**/authentication/login-form.phtml**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->getElement('username') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->getElement('password') ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

When I render the form thenI get following exception:

```
Message: Plugin by name 'GetElement' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:/wamp/www/databox/application/views\helpers/
```

Where I am going wrong. Should I enter any information in application.ini or Bootstrap.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the form to your view script to make it work.

```
public function someAction()
{
    $this->view->form = new Form_Login();
}
```

in your view script you can receive the elements via

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><?= $this->form->getElement('username'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?= $this->form->getElement('password'); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I am doing the same thing in someAction and rendering form in **some.phtml** like `$this->form->render();`. But I think form elements should be rendered in **login-form.phtml**.

Comment: so you have an view script without an associated action where the login form shall render?

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: I don't know about this and I am working on zend forms first time. Can you please explain more. thanks

Comment: @Awan I was asking for clarification of what you want to achieve. The usual way to use your form is the approach you see in the ZF Quickstart. Could you describe what you want to achieve within which files and actions?

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: I want to create form elements in **Login.php**. Then I want to decorate form elements in **login-form.phtml** in my own style. Now I want to use this form anywhere in the application. So Then I will create form instance in **someAction** like this `$this->view->form = new Form_Login();` and when I render the form in **some.phtml** (`$this->form->render();`), it should render the form with style described in **login-form.phtml**.

Comment: @Awan so you want to change the default decorators, you should read [the manual on decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.form.decorators.html) and design your application accordingly.

Comment: @Awan: A little more color on @Samuel Herzog's good response: Sounds like you need to remove/disable the default decorators on the form and use a single `ViewScript` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->setDecorators( array( array( 'viewScript', array( 'viewScript' =>'/authentication/login-form.phtml','form'=>$form ) ) ) );
```

and then in view

```
$this->form->getElement('elementName');
```